# In WinForms CheckListBox can you make subitems?

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

I am making a .Net WinForms application and have a CheckListBox and I want to give one of the items in the list sub-items. (i.e. Item 1, Item 1a, Item 1b ....) is this possible to do or should I be using another way of making a list of checkbox items? I am brand new to WinForms and this is my first app.

Comment: Don't you mean "webforms"? (After all, you are talking about ASP.NET.)

Comment: Is there anything called **ASP.Net WinForms**?

Comment: What you want is a `TreeView`

Comment: Sorry meant .Net WinForms, type ASP.Net was just a habbit

Comment: I tried the TreeView but that is not showing the box for checkmarks. Is there some setting I have to toggle to have it be a checklist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, use a [Tree View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) and inorder to get checkboxes to display, set the [TreeView.CheckBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes.aspx) Property to true.